# Windows USB HID Report Length

Tags: windows, usb, hid

I am developing a USB HID device using an STMicro microcontroller. I started with STMicro's HID example which works fine. I am using C++ on Windows 7 64-bit for the PC side. I have an application that works with my device. There is one thing I can't figure out, however.

The example firmware only allowed sending and receiving 2 bytes at a time, which is determined by a HIDP_CAPS.OutputReportByteLength and InputReportByteLength. I would like to send more data than this at once, but I can't figure out how to increase the report lengths. I successfully changed the endpoint wMaxPacketSize, the VID and PID, and a few other things, but I can't figure out how Windows is calculating the in and out report lengths. There doesn't seem to be any fields in my report or device descriptions that indicate this length, but I can't imagine where else it might be coming from.

Can anyone tell me how Windows determines the HIDP_CAPS.OutputReportByteLength and HIDP_CAPS.InputReportByteLength?

How can I increase these lengths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I thought I would post here in case anyone else needs to know. I'm not entirely sure I really understand it all, so if I made a mistake, someone please correct me.

I had to change the report description in my firmware. I had several usages. Windows gets the report description and figures out which usage requires the longest length and uses that length. On one of my input reports I made the following changes (the input report is just an array of bytes in firmware):

`0x27, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,  //Logical maximum is 4 bytes long, and has a value of 0xFFFFFFFF
0x95, 0x01,                    //There is one report
0x75, 0x20,                    //There are 32 bits per report`

I did something similar for the output, but there is no report number field (0x95).

Windows now tells me I can send and receive 5 bytes, which I believe means the end point plus report number times report size.

Comment: Can you post your complete HID report descriptor? If you have a report id in it then you must prefix any reports with that id...that  accounts for the extra byte.

Comment: You can get the entire original project here: https://github.com/zegervdv/PS2-controller/tree/master/STM32F072B-Discovery_FW_V1.0.1/Projects/Peripheral_Examples/USB_Example

Comment: Not a biggie, but there is a minor error in the HID report descriptor of that example...
  0x25, 0xFF,   //Logical Maximum (255)
...really means "Logical Maximum -1". It should be:
 0x26, 0xFF, 0x00,  //Logical Maximum (255)
Also, specifying 0xA0 instead of 0xA1 0x00 for the Physical Collection is a gray area. The spec does not explicitly say what default value is assumed if a value is omitted...but I think zero would be reasonable.
Other than that, no report descriptor is present, so I would expect 5 byte reports to be seen (one each for Ry, Rx, Y, X and the button bits).